# I want submenu should open on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu, megamenu

I am using bootstrap mega menu. On hover it opens sub menu but sometime it takes click event also and sub menu got stuck.
In my javascript there is not mention any click event just have hover code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").hover(
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("100");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    },
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("100");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }
  );
});
```

reference:
        https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-slide-down-on-hover-with-carousel

Comment: did you include the bootstrap css/js files, both?

Comment: yes, i did but still it stuck not everytime but few time like in 100 click 1 time it stuck

Comment: If you share the browser and OS in the question, someone can try replicating your issue - also if you can replicate it with a working minimal example in the code snippet, you'll get help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **Hover** event to **Click** event and make it "toggleable".

Theres an example for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropdownOpen = null; // Toggle status
    $(".dropdown").click(function() {
        if(dropdownOpen === this){
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400"); // Close clicked  
            dropdownOpen = null; // Reset
        }
        else{
            $('.dropdown-menu').not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400"); // Close all     
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown("400"); // Open clicked
            dropdownOpen = this; // Set
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('open');  
     });
     // Hide when click outside the element
     $(window).click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400"); // Close all     
     });
});
```

You can try this code in the same reference example you posted above.

**Edit:** I added the dropdown hidden when click outside the element

Comment: its working fine but i need to close submenu when i click outside of menu